# Is this right usage of Strategy pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, graph, strategy-pattern

I have a complex Network represented as hypergraph
Hypergraph vertices are from various type:image,tag ....
I have also various type of hyper-edge that relate vertices
Homogenous HyperEdge :ImageImageHyperEdge ,TagTagHyperHedge ...
Heterogenous HyperEdge :ImageTagHyperEdge , ImageTagLocationHyperEdge...

So I think Strategy pattern is useful for such situation 
I quickly drew this  uml diagram 
[image]

Is this right usage of Strategy pattern ?

another question 
for example 
for image vertex may has different heterogenous hyper-edge type 
ImageTag ,ImageTagLocation 
how to do this ?

Comment: I don't really understand where the Strategy class is in there or what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I added the uml diagram

Comment: I still can't spot a Strategy class in that diagram.

Comment: I have 2 strategy for constructing hyperEdge depending on it type:homogeneous or heterogeneous

Comment: When it's about creation of objects: Strategy is not a creational pattern. it's a behavioral pattern.

Comment: but for example 
Image vertex and tag vertex do not implement the same type of homogenousHyperedge